# Play Framework intermittently respects JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, ubuntu, playframework-2.0

java6 is the default java on our ubuntu box, and I have java7 in another directory with JAVA_HOME pointing at java7.

Using sudo -E to maintain the JAVA_HOME env variable in a non-Play project folder:

```
$ sudo -E /usr/share/play/play
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_17 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

This is not a play application!
```

Ok great, play is using java 7! But if you switch to the directory of an actual Play app and run the same command...

```
$ sudo -E /usr/share/play/play
[info] Loading project definition from /var/playtest/project

[info] Set current project to playtest (in build file:/var/playtest/)
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.6.0_26 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
```

Now play is starting up with java6. What gives, is play starting more shells or something and not maintaining the appropriate JAVA_HOME? How would you configure using non-default jdk installations with sudo for Play?

Edit: I added an 'echo $JAVA_HOME' to the /usr/share/play/play script and it spits out the correct JDK path in both app and non-app folders: '/usr/share/jdk7/bin/java', however java6 still starts up instead of java7 for actual Play projects.

Maybe this is an actual bug I should open a ticket for? Play knows the correct path at the start of execution, but forgets it and starts using default at some point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was just marked as fixed at GitHub, woot

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/985

Answer (score 0):

There's a [ticket](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/231-play20-does-not-honour-java_home) for this, though it seems to be resolved in March 2012, and Play 2.1.1 has been released this year. Based on your description it would look like it's not.